# How to override default errors in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to override default validation errors. My custom messages need information such as  length of the user input - just like the default ones.

How can I include variables like `length` in my messages?

I tried this code:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['myfield']
        error_messages = {
            'myfield': {
                'required': 'My error',
                'min_length': _(u'You wrote only %(length)d chars'),
                'max_length': _(u'You wrote %(length)d chars - too much.'),
            },
        }
```

Error I get:

```
KeyError at /
u'length'
```

Comment: Have you tried without naming? I mean: 'You wrote %d chars'.

Comment: `TypeError at /
%d format: a number is required, not dict`

Comment: Hmmm.. DecimalField uses ['max'](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L317-L332), FileField uses 'max' and 'length'. Maybe 'max' works for you.

Comment: This is more accurate https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L254-L287. You can use 'limit_value' and 'show_value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min_length` is applied to `django.core.validators.MinLengthValidator` which has default message as:

```
message = _('Ensure this value is %(limit_value)s (it is %(show_value)s).')
```

And params as:

```
params = {'limit_value': self.limit_value, 'show_value': cleaned}
```

Thus try to change `'length'` to `'show_value'`.